# Can Rust match on a type (not a value) to conditionally compile code, like C++'s `if constexpr`?

Tags: rust

I was trying to write the following code:

```rust
trait Foo {
    type Output;

    fn bar() -> Self::Output;
    fn baz() -> Self::Output {
        const match Self::Output { // imaginary syntax
            () => (),        // compile this statement only if Output == Unit
            _ => bar()       // Otherwise compile this statement
        }
    }
}
```

Since `Output` is a generic type, I can't instantiate a value (and it could be expensive to do so). In C++, I would have just used `if constexpr(std::same<Output, void>::value)` or created a template function and specialized it for `void`, but I didn't find a way to do it in Rust.

Comment: Expanding on the duplicate suggestion, add another trait that `Self::Output` must implement and then implement the new trait for the unit type and others. [applied](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2086f149beef80b9b525343a2d358e0c)