# How to match Self on associated method of enum for a given trait

Tags: enums, rust

Before starting, I wasn't able to adapt neither [how to match on data type in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596628/how-to-match-on-data-type-in-rust)
nor the updated version of Shepmaster to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847391/can-rust-match-on-a-type-not-a-value-to-conditionally-compile-code-like-cs) I had.

---

I would like to be able to implement the `Token` trait for each variant of the enum `BinOp`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, std::cmp::PartialEq)]
enum BinOp {
    Add,
    Sub
}

trait Token {
    fn regex() -> &'static str;
}
```

---

Neither this works (this is what I would have like to write)

EDIT: fix typo: `impl Token for BinOp` instead of `impl Token for BinOp::Add`

```rust
impl Token for BinOp {
    fn regex() -> &'static str{
        match Self {
            BinOp::Add => "\\+",
            BinOp::Sub => "-"
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
        match Self {
              ^^^^ 
the `Self` constructor can only be used with tuple or unit structs


the `Self` constructor can only be used with tuple or unit structs
```

Nor that

```rust
impl Token for BinOp::Add {
    fn regex() -> &'static str{
         "\\+"
    }
}
```

```rust
impl Token for BinOp::Add {
               ^^^^^^^^^^ not a type
expected type, found variant `BinOp::Add`
```

---

If the above code could be written, I would have liked to be able to use it like this

```rust
let add: BinOp = BinOp::Add;
let regex: &str = BinOp::Add::regex();
```

---

Is there a better way than doing the following (witch is way too much verbose)?

```rust
#[derive(Debug, std::cmp::PartialEq)]
struct Add;
#[derive(Debug, std::cmp::PartialEq)]
struct Sub;
#[derive(Debug, std::cmp::PartialEq)]
enum BinOp {
    Add(Add),
    Sub(Sub)
}

trait Token {
    fn regex() -> &'static str;
}

impl Token for Add {
    fn regex() -> &'static str{
         "\\+"
    }
}
impl Token for Sub {
    fn regex() -> &'static str{
         "-"
    }
}
```

```rust
let add: BinOp = BinOp::Add(Add);
let regex: &str = Add::regex();
```

Is this unfortunately a current limitation of Rust? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, an enum variant is not a type in Rust, so you must stick with your "verbose" version.

There is [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2593) that would make variants as types, but even if it is implemented, (if I read it correctly) you won't be able to make them implement a trait anyway.

---

However, in your very case, since your variants don't hold any value, you can write something like that:

```
#[derive(Debug, std::cmp::PartialEq, Clone, Copy)]
enum BinOp {
    Add,
    Sub
}

trait Token {
    fn regex(self) -> &'static str;
}

impl Token for BinOp {
    fn regex(self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            BinOp::Add => "\\+",
            BinOp::Sub => "-",
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(BinOp::Add.regex(), "\\+");
    assert_eq!(BinOp::Sub.regex(), "-");
}
```